# A better approach than Oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

We're supposed to update some columns in a table 'tab1' with some values(which can be picked up from a different table 'tab2'). Now 'tab1' is getting new records inserted almost every few seconds(from MQ by a different system). 
We want to design a solution that will update 'tab1' as soon as there is a new record added to 'tab1'. It doesn't have to be done in the same moment as the record is added, but the sooner its updated, the better. We were considering what can be the best way to do it:

1) First we thought of a 'before insert' trigger on tab1, so we can update the record - but that design was vetted out by our Architect, since the organization doesn't allow use of database triggers(don't know why, but that is a restriction, we have been asked to live with)

2) Second we thought, we will create a stored procedure which will perform the updates to records in 'tab1'. This stored procedure will be called within an long-running loop from a shell script. After every iteration there will be a pause of lets say 3 secs and then next loop will kick off, which will again call the stored proc. So this job will run 12 AM to 11:59 PM and then restarted every night.

My question is - is there a database only solution to this? Any other solutions are also welcome, but simplicity of design will be a huge plus. One colleague was wondering if there is a 'trigger-like' solution, which will perform the job within the database itself - so we don't have to write a shell script.

Any pointers will be appreciated!

Comment: Not sue what you mean by 'trigger-like'. You could use a [scheduled job](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/schedover.htm#ADMIN033) to call the procedure instead of a shell script, which would keep everything inside the database. Are those allowed?

Comment: The database-only solution is called "a trigger" which you've said isn't allowed by way of executive fiat. Best of luck.

Comment: I would have to agree with @Alex Poole in that, if you want to have a 'database-only' solution, create a stored procedure and schedule it as a job within the database.

Comment: It would also be interesting to dig in to why triggers are banned. I'd guess it's for performance reasons; but if so I'd imagine getting and setting the value in a trigger is going to be less expensive that doing a separate step to identify and update the rows afterwards. Might be worth discussing that more with your architect, an exemption might be justified.

Comment: One other thought; are the tab2 values static? If so maybe you could have a view (possibly materialized) that joins the tables, instead of storing the duplicate values in tab1 at all. That's a big 'if' though - you might be capturing the tab2 values as they were when the tab1 row was created, in which case *any* gap might be bad, and you're back to a trigger.

Comment: I have seen overuse of triggers, but they definitely have proper use cases, and this seems like one.  Why incur the overhead of polling?  That is a waste of resources.  Insert rates of a record every few seconds is minuscule.  Do inserts on your tab1 table take long for some reason?  You could write a trigger and post to an AQ for async processing if that it a worry.  Have to question your "Architect's" reasoning on this.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks But scheduled job is not allowed either. The reason is cost effectiveness(from engaging support team perspective) - in that case we would have to go to Maestro/Cron scheduling. And i completely agree that DB trigger would have been so perfect! But my Architect is not ready to share more details at this point. No, tab2 is not static - so updates have to be done on real time and we can't make a view to expose the updated data, b'cos that would mean the UI team which is reading final data from 'tab1' would also need to change their code - not allowed for this project

Comment: Hi OldProgrammer, No inserts are not slow, infact there is no performance problems b'cos of triggers that i am not aware of - just i have been told not to use triggers - banned organization wide

Comment: i don't understand "*will update 'tab1' as soon as there is a new record added to 'tab1'*" - so you want to turn an INSERT into an UPDATE?

Comment: I'm tempted to consider whether something effective could be done with a materialised view, or just a materialised view log, but I bet they're banned too. I guess it's an interesting intellectual exercise to consider whether there is a way of doing this if all the logical, obvious, and efficient solutions are denied, but none of them are going to be logical, obvious, or efficient. I guess in that context the answer to the question, "is there a database only solution to this?", is "No".

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name. Actually not, i meant that as soon as a record is inserted into tab1, my job should update certain columns in that record. So first there will be an insert by someone's job and then my job will update that inserted record

Comment: Hi David, i also feel there is no DB only solution to this, but will wait a lil more in case someone comes up with a novel idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. <s>**Triggers** The obvious solution.</s>
2. <s>**[DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI)** Another obvious solution.</s>
3. **[Continuous Query Notification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_cqnotif.htm#ARPLS201)** This would be a "trigger-like" solution.  It's meant to call an application when the results of a specific query would be different.  But you can call PL/SQL instead of an application, and the query could be a simple `select * from tab1;` which would fire on any table changes.  Normally I'd hope an architect would be to look at this solution and say, "a trigger would be a lot simpler".
4. **[DBMS_JOBS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_job.htm#ARPLS019)** This is the old version of DBMS_SCHEDULER and is not as good.  But it's different and maybe it won't be caught as an unauthorized feature.
5. **Ignore the Architect** The problem isn't that he disapproved of using triggers or jobs; there *may* be legitimate reasons to ban those technologies.  The problem is that he rejected a sound idea without clearly articulating why it wasn't allowed.  If he understood databases, or cared about your project, or acted like a professional, he would have said something like, "Oh, I'm sorry, I know that's the typical way to do this, but we don't allow it because of X, Y, Z."

Comment: Hi Jon, Sorry for the delayed reply. yes, continuous Query notification sounds promising. I'll take it back to my Architect and yes, completely agree  with #5 above. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

Q: Is there a database only solution to this?

Unlikely, given all the limitations on your architecture.

Q: Any other solutions are also welcomed

It seems your likely solution is to have your application handle what would normally be handled by a trigger or stored procedure.  Just do it all in one transaction.

Comment: Hi tale852150, i think that is what i will end up doing. But will wait before accepting the answer in case someone comes up with some alternative

Comment: @JavaTec Sounds fair enough to me.